# Keeping only True if one of two columns is true

Tags: python

I have two columns like below.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| True | False |
| True | True |
| False | True |
| False | False |

I want to get

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| True | False | True | False |
| True | True | False | False |
| False | True | False | True |
| False | False | False | False |

I was trying to use the XOR operator, but couldn't figure out how to make it only return true if the specific column was true.

Comment: Is it a `pandas` DataFrame?

Comment: Column C is (A and not B); Column D is (not A and B)

Comment: This is a pandas dataframe. Thanks for responses.

Comment: Thank you @Pignotto brain fart on the logic. Thanks.

Comment: Use the bitwise XOR operator `^`, i.e. `df['Column A'] ^ df['Column B']`

Answer (score 2):

XOR is the wrong function. You want `A AND NOT B` and `NOT A AND B`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [True, True, False, False],
    'B': [False, True, True, False]})

df['C'] = df['A'] & ~df['B']
df['D'] = ~df['A'] & df['B']
df
```

```
       A      B      C      D
0   True  False   True  False
1   True   True  False  False
2  False   True  False   True
3  False  False  False  False
```

If it helps, these operations are called non-implication and converse non-implication, and Wikipedia has a table here: [Template:Logical connectives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Logical_connectives)

Comment: Thank you for the link and explanation this is exactly what I ended up doing.